# How to use the shadow DOM delegatesFocus option with Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, focus, web-component, shadow-dom

The Google Developers primer on Shadow DOM [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#focus) explains how `delegatesFocus`can be used to focus the first focusable element inside shadow DOM when a non-focusable area is clicked.

It can be done when attaching the shadow root and passing the option `delegatesFocus: true`.

With Polymer, I can't find a way to pass that option. I can't even do something like `this.shadowRoot.delegatesFocus = true` because it throws exception saying that property is read only.

Here's the sample element.

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer-element.html">
<dom-module id="pp-input">
  <template>

    <style>
      /* shadow DOM styles go here */
      :host {
        border: 2px solid;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
      }
      .content {
        font-size: 1em;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Click Here!</h2>
    <!-- shadow DOM goes here -->
    <input type="text" on-input="onInput" value="[[value]]" />
  </template>

  <script>
    class PPInput extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "pp-input";
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          value: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            value: true
          }
        }
      }
      onInput(e) {
        this.value = e.target.value;
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = "";
      }

    }
    customElements.define(PPInput.is, PPInput);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<pp-input value="asdf"></pp-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update - A cleaner approach

Creating your own shadow DOM is possible as mentioned in this link

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#create-your-own-shadow-root

---

Courtesy to a friend, found this issue on GitHub.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3988

Apparently the `attachShadow()` options aren't exposed via Polymer but the following can be done to override how Polymer creates shadow DOM.

```
class PPInput extends Polymer.Element {

    // code...

    _attachDom(dom) {
        if (!this.shadowRoot) {
            this.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open',
                delegatesFocus: true
            });
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(dom);
        }
        return this.shadowRoot;
    }
}
```

Doing this makes the element works as expected.

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer-element.html">
<dom-module id="pp-input">
  <template>

    <style>
      /* shadow DOM styles go here */
      :host {
        border: 2px solid;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
      }
      .content {
        font-size: 1em;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Click Here!</h2>
    <!-- shadow DOM goes here -->
    <input type="text" on-input="onInput" value="[[value]]" />
  </template>

  <script>
    class PPInput extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "pp-input";
      }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          value: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            value: true
          }
        };
      }

      onInput(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.value = e.target.value;
      }
      _attachDom(dom) {
        if (!this.shadowRoot) {
          this.attachShadow({
            mode: "open",
            delegatesFocus: true
          });
          this.shadowRoot.appendChild(dom);
        }
        return this.shadowRoot;
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = "";
      }
    }
    customElements.define(PPInput.is, PPInput);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<pp-input></pp-input>
```